# Return Line exporting in .txt

Tags: python

I try to generate 300k urls with python in a text file:

```
with open(r'somefile.txt') as f_out:
for i in range(100, 120):
f_out.write(r'www.website.com/{}\n'.format(i))
```

But the result is:

```
www.website.com/
101www.websitecom/
102www.website.com/
```

etc

Comment: This obviously cannot be your real code because the file is opened in read mode. Please provide a _real_ [mcve].

Comment: Wtf ? yes i got a 'w' after 'somefile.txt') but that wasn't relevant in this example, just asking about the "blackslash n "

Comment: @johnashu yes it is, the "\n" doesn't work in open i may use print but i can figure it how.

People, stop trolling or just bulling you are useless as f.

Comment: We can't help you figure out what's wrong with your code if we can't reproduce the problem. So yes, until you provide a [mcve], we're pretty useless. The code you posted does _not_ produce such a file.

Comment: Lol @Aran-Fey everybody get the good result except you. Retry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, you want to output the URL's like this:

```
www.website.com/100
www.website.com/101
www.website.com/102
```

The solution I came up with based on the code you provided was to use the `print()` function with the `file` argument ([Documentation of the `file` argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print))

```
with open(r'somefile.txt', "w") as f_out:
    for i in range(100, 120):
        print(r'www.website.com/{}'.format(i), file=f_out)
```

You might also want to read about opening files in `write` mode [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open).

Answer (score 1):

I put  the data into a variable first.. it prints and saves no problem..

```
with open('somefile.txt', 'a') as f_out:
    for i in range(100, 120):
        data = 'www.website.com/{}\n'.format(i)
        print(data)
        f_out.write(data)
```

Comment: no problem. just try to make sure you have plenty of detail in the question. people might come across wrong but everyone here genuinely just wants to solve the problem! please select a correct answer using the green tick so future users can quickly find a correct answer! :)